# On Pressed for FloatingActionButton is showing only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

If I initialized the FloatingActionButton as "incrementWidgetButton" in a class like below

```
Widget incrementWidgetButton = FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,// why this error, only static member can be accessed
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  );
```

and then call that button widget in my column widget like below

```
    floatingActionButton: incrementWidgetButton
```

[The code error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqG9z.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it that you get that error `only static member can be accessed` is that when the class is being initialized with all properties it doesn't know about the method `_incrementCounter`.

You can solve this problem by creating a function that returns your `FloatingActionButton`:

```
Widget incrementWidgetButton() => FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  );
```

After that you add it like so in your app:

```
floatingActionButton: incrementWidgetButton()
```

Comment: sorry I am a beginer in flutter , what are the initializers here ? are they FloatingActionButton initializers or main class initializers  ?

Answer (score 0):

As it says

> Only static members can be access in initializers

explains itself.

The idea is that the initializers are executed before the constructors are called and hence the program doesn't know about the methods you define yet.

So you can either of the three things..

1. Make your method static
2. Directly define the floatingActionButton in the scaffold attribute itself.
3. Do what @fayeed told.

Comment: if I put static in incrementWidgetButton , then the function _incrementCounter should be static also. And if do so then I cannot use setState inside.